# Why problem of Graph colouring is NP-Hard?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I am studying graph coloring and trying to find why graph coloring is NP-Hard. Please share your thoughts or share any resources related to this.
Thank you in Advance.

Comment: It can't be any harder than NP-complete (showing that it's in NP is a good exercise!) and problems tend to be as hard as they 'can be' unless there's a hidden structure. Why would you expect it to _not_ be NP-complete?

Comment: A formal proof will do something like encode 3-SAT as a graph coloring. Is that the kind of thing you're looking for?

Comment: If you're interested in this kind of thing, you'll do well to sit down with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computers_and_Intractability

Comment: In fact, the problem of proving 3-colorability is NP-complete is given as an exercise in that book, with the suggestion of using 3-SAT.

Comment: Have you had a chance to consult that book, Sadik?

Comment: Not yet, Gerry.